# How can one become a YouTube translator?

Tags: youtube, translation

YouTube Help explains how to [buy translations for videos, titles, & descriptions](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2780526) (the comma after "titles" is quoted as-is - maybe they need a translator ;-)

But how can one **sell** translations for videos, titles, & descriptions? Just curious how do companies get to offer their services there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YouTube generally uses big outsourcing contractors for this. I'll try to get an answer from my contacts as to which one.